# why function socket.send(array_byte) not send full data?

Tags: sockets, python-2.7, arrays, asyncore

please help me
i use asyncore to code server in python (python 2.7).

with packet (is array byte) have len(packet) < 1288 : send ok.

but with packet have len(packet) > 1288, i call socket.send(packet_byte), client not recv full data

p/s:
client recv:

```
print 'Received:', data, len(data)

...."e0 ng\u00e0y th\u1ee9 bao nhi\u00eau c\u1ee7a th\u00e1ng \u0111\u1ea7u ti\u00ean c\u1ee7a n\u0103m d\u01b0\u01a1ng l\u1ecbch ho\u1eb7c n\u0103m t\u00e0i ch\u00ednh \u0111\u1ed1i v\u1edbi lo\u1ea1i thu\u1ebf khai v\u00e0 n\u1ed9p theo n\u0103m?", "answers": ["Ng\u00e0y 10",  1288
```

Comment: It does send it all. But there's nothing that says the client will receive it all at once.

Comment: data = s.recv(20024) and server only send 17000 byte

Comment: i used socket.sendall but no effect

Comment: Your receiver needs to keep calling recv() repeatedly until it has received all of the bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't have to. According to "socket" docs:

> send() Returns the number of bytes sent. Applications are responsible
>   for checking that all data has been sent; if only some of the data was
>   transmitted, the application needs to attempt delivery of the
>   remaining data.

And here comes slightly modified sample implementation from https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#socket-howto :

```
def mysend(sock, msg):
    totalsent = 0
    while totalsent < MSGLEN:
        sent = sock.send(msg[totalsent:])
        if sent == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        totalsent = totalsent + sent
```

**Note:** In fact handling sockets directly is NOT needed with asyncore. Asyncore wraps it for You (consider inheriting *asyncore.dispatcher_with_send* and using its *send()* method).

Comment: The documentation you cite is incorrect. In blocking mode, the underlying C send() function blocks until all the data is sent. It's required by Posix. It is the recv() method that isn't obliged to transfer more than one byte.

Comment: Agree, but in case of asyncore, one would most often deal with "sock.setblocking(0)" pre-configured socket (done by _dispatcher.__init__()_ ).